# react-native redux - reducer changing array elements

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a state, part of which is an array called 'numbers'. One of the actions is to change the state in the following way: all the odd numbers should be changed to zero, all the even numbers should be kept. For example:

```
previous state
[9, 3, 2, 6, 8]

action
new state
[0, 0, 2, 6, 8]
```

action creator:

```
export const turnEven = () => {
  return {
    type: TURN_EVEN
  };
};
```

reducer:

```
case TURN_EVEN:
      return [...state, numbers: state.numbers.map(
        (i) => (i % 2 === 0 ? i : 0))];
```

This one produces an error: unexpected token, expected ,
... and the 'return' line is being indicated as the location of the error.
Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code that you've shared:

```
case TURN_EVEN:
      return [...state, numbers: state.numbers.map(
        (i) => (i % 2 === 0 ? i : 0))];
```

It looks like the state of this reducer has different properties, one of them being `numbers`.

Maybe you wanted to do this instead:

```
case TURN_EVEN:
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    state,
    { numbers: state.numbers.map(i => (i % 2 === 0 ? i : 0)) }
  );
```

I haven't seen the rest of your reducer, so maybe I don't have enough context but I would encourage you to try to make a reducer for each one of the properties of the state, one of them `numbers` and then use [`combineReducers` to combine them into one](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html). Small functions are easier to deal with.

If you did that, then you could have a reducer like this one for numbers:

```
const initialState = [];
const numbersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  swicth (action.type) {
    case TURN_EVEN:
      return state.map(i => (i % 2 === 0 ? i : 0));
    // Other action types here...
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually use combineReducers and have a separate reducer for the 'number' property of the state. The example above worked fine. Thank you.